# Word is not getting added until the page is refreshed in TableItem component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

TableItem component added without any data in UI. Could somebody help on this. On refereshing the UI, added data is shown with details in TableItem component.

Table Component Code

```
import TableItem from "./TableItem";

function Table({ searchWord }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const dictData = useSelector((state) => state.dictionary);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDictionaryAsync());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <table className="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Word</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {dictData &&
          dictData
            .filter((e) =>
              searchWord === ""
                ? e
                : e.word &&
                  e.word.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())
            )
            .map((item) => (
              <TableItem item={item} key={item.id} searchWord={searchWord} />
            ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
export default Table;
```

Below is the TableItem Component Code which i am trying to update,
When i add a word to dictionary it will fetch the details from the server and display it in the React app.

```
function TableItem({ item }) {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{item.word}</td>
        <td>
          <b style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
            {item.items && item.items[0].category} -{" "}
          </b>
          {item.items && truncate(item.items[0].definitions[0])}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm " onClick={openModal}>
            View
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} ariaHideApp={true}>
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h3 className="modal-word-header">
            {item.word && item.word.toUpperCase()}
          </h3>
          <button
            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
            onClick={() => setModal(false)}
          >
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="model-content">
          <p>
            {item.items &&
              item.items.map((e) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <i>{e.category}</i>
                    <ul>
                      {e.definitions.map((def) => {
                        return <li>{def}</li>;
                      })}
                    </ul>
                  </>
                );
              })}
          </p>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better add your TableItem component code!

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine and updated the UI on change in the Data in TableItem,

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDictionaryAsync());
  }, [dispatch, dictData]);         *<--updated code*
```